# Activating an event manually in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, events, simulation, anylogic

I'd like to do a simulation with specific implementations, which don't have to occur by every run.
I don't want to have them occurring randomly, but activating them manually, so I can see how the simulation runs with and without those events.

I was thinking about bringing them in by a small occurrence rate within the simulation time, but I'd rather control them by myself. Alternatively, maybe there is a way to set an event which I could *deactivate* manually? If that is possible, It sure could also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a button and a function `executeMyEvent()`.

In the function, write the stuff that should happen when you click the button.

In the button, write `executeMyEvent();`.

At runtime, click the button whenever you like and the code is executed. But only if and when you want.